# Adding formatted dates as xticks in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a list of dates to Matplotlib `xticks` and when I do that the actual plot disappears keeping only `xticks`.

For example, I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import (DateFormatter, rrulewrapper, RRuleLocator, YEARLY)

# Generate random data and dates
data = np.random.randn(10000)
start = dt.datetime.strptime("2019-03-14", "%Y-%m-%d")
end = dt.datetime.strptime("2046-07-30", "%Y-%m-%d")
date = [start + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

rule = rrulewrapper(YEARLY, byeaster=1, interval=2)
loc = RRuleLocator(rule)
formatter = DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=10)
plt.plot(data)
# ax.set_xlim(min(date), max(date))
plt.show()
```

This code plots the data which looks like this:

[image: test-1]

Now if I uncomment `ax.set_xlim(min(date), max(date))` and rerun the code I get:

[image: test-2]

You can see that I only get the dates, formatted correctly but not the plot. I am not sure what the problem here. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

If I change `data = np.random.randn(10000)` to `data = np.random.randn(1000000)`, then I am able to see the plot Which is not what I want

Comment: Note that `plt.plot` takes two arguments, `x` and `y` for the data along the x and y axis respectively. If you only call `plt.plot(y)` matplotlib has no chance of knowing what you want to show on the x axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is by passing the `date` array along with `data` array in the plot method. That is with the given example it will be:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import (DateFormatter, rrulewrapper, RRuleLocator, YEARLY)

# Generate random data and dates
data = np.random.randn(10000)
start = dt.datetime.strptime("2019-03-14", "%Y-%m-%d")
end = dt.datetime.strptime("2046-07-30", "%Y-%m-%d")
date = [start + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]

rule = rrulewrapper(YEARLY, byeaster=1, interval=2)
loc = RRuleLocator(rule)
formatter = DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=10)
plt.plot(date, data)
ax.set_xlim(min(date), max(date))
plt.show()
```

Then you'll get:

[image]

See [matplotlib.pyplot.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your data is plotted, but not at the correct location. If you go along [that example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) you would need to add something like `fig.autofmt_xdate()` to your code.

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: Have you tried converting your datetime to numpy datetime as shown in the reference?